# Is there any way to check which quests I have completed the subquest for?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate, there were in-game achievements for doing subquests (At least, I remember them). I assume Monster Hunter Generations has them as well, and because I'm a goofball I'd like to earn these. Is there any way to see which quests I have completed the subquests for?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no such award in 4U.

Comment: Huh, I think you're right and I just remembered wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to check which subquests you have completed.